# Match to return same row not woking for me? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Hi Everyone my name is Ray

```
col A   col B       col c     col d (what i want to display)
Emoji | Sentiment | message | sentiment_message (goes in seperate sheets)
      POSITIVE            POSITIVE
      POSITIVE            POSITIVE
      POSITIVE            POSITIVE
      POSITIVE            POSITIVE
      NEGATIVE            POSITIVE
      NEGATIVE            NEGATIVE
      POSITIVE            NEGATIVE
```

I want to check if the emoji in col c is present in col a, I can do that with this code

```
=if(match(c2, a:a, 1), b:b, 1)
```

The problem is the b:b, i want the respective sentiment from each match.

Comment: Google Sheets doesn't allow the insertion of code comments, so I edited the question to move the comment out of the code formatted line, also I added the equal sign at the beginning of the formula and edited tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `VLOOKUP` instead of match, as it will return the sentiment instead of the value if you want.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,false)
```

[image]